# How to create launcher icon

Tags: matlab

I recently installed Matlab R2013a and it is working fine, however the only way I can start it is by running `/usr/local/MATLAB/R2013a/bin/matlab` in the terminal. If I type in `matlab` it says command not found, and I can't seem to get an icon in the side-bar launcher. How can I make it so I can run from the command matlab or from a launcher?

Edit: I have created a link so I can launch it by typing `matlab` in the terminal. I still can't get the unity icon launcher working though. I managed to create an icon via a `matlab.desktop` file in `/usr/share/applications`. When I click it, it launches Matlab, but after the initial loading screen Matlab shuts down instead of launching the application. It works through the terminal though. My `matlab.desktop` file is:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Name=Matlab
Comment=Matlab R2013a
Icon=/usr/share/icons/Matlab.png
Exec=/usr/local/MATLAB/R2013a/bin/matlab
Categories=Office
Terminal=false`
```

Comment: you sure the matlab.desktop file has executable permissions? If it does not, it won't launch.

Answer (score 21):

The lock to launcher is indeed not working for matlab. There is however a .desktop file that is part of the Matlab installation.

```
sudo ln /usr/share/app-install/desktop/matlab-support:matlab.desktop /usr/share/applications/matlab.desktop
```

You have to update a few things in this file (matlab.desktop):

```
[Desktop Entry]
X-AppInstall-Package=matlab-support
X-AppInstall-Popcon=3
X-AppInstall-Section=multiverse

Version=1.0
Type=Application
Terminal=false
Exec=matlab -desktop
Name=MATLAB
Icon=_usr_share_icons_hicolor_48x48_apps_matlab
Categories=Development;Math;Science
Comment=Scientific computing environment
StartupNotify=true
StartupWMClass=com-mathworks-util-PostVMInit

X-Ubuntu-Gettext-Domain=app-install-data
```

Give the icon an absolute file path by changing the icon path above to

```
Icon=/usr/share/app-install/icons/_usr_share_icons_hicolor_48x48_apps_matlab.png
```

And change:

```
Terminal=true
```

Now you should be able to lock the icon to the launcher as well as start matlab from there.

Comment: This is working.

Comment: And `Terminal=true` is not required.

Comment: This is a nice and complete answer +1. @Isaac Vandermeulen should consider accepting this.

Comment: FYI: If you use the `-desktop` argument with the `matlab` command you don't need `Terminal=true` in the launcher file

Comment: @TylerDurden. Thanks. That used to be necessary, so I'll keep it there as reference.

Comment: @AnnevanRossum I modified the .desktop file but Matlab still doesn't run from the icon. Also `sudo ln /usr/share/app-install/desktop/matlab-support:matlab.desktop /usr/share/applications/matlab.desktop` gives me this message `ln: failed to create hard link '/usr/share/applications/matlab.desktop': File exists` What do I do?

Answer (score 12):

> To add an entry to the launcher and some other features, install the matlab-support package:

`sudo apt-get install matlab-support`

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MATLAB

Comment: It works just fine!

Comment: This should be accepted as best answer.

Answer (score 10):

For me this works perfectly ...

Open a terminal and then

1.download your own icon-

```
sudo wget http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/21/Matlab_Logo.png -O /usr/share/icons/matlab.png
```

2.give your access permission

```
sudo touch /usr/share/applications/matlab.desktop
```

3.edit your .desktop file

```
sudo gedit /usr/share/applications/matlab.desktop
```

4.and paste the following into the document.

```
#!/usr/bin/env xdg-open
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Icon=/usr/share/icons/matlab.png
Name=MATLAB R2014a
Comment=Start MATLAB - The Language of Technical Computing
Exec=matlab -desktop
Categories=Development;
```

that's it..! Save, and you should have a new desktop shortcut in your launcher

Answer (score 6):

In your matlab.desktop file, you need to specify that you want to execute in the desktop.

Your Exec= should look like this:

```
 Exec=/usr/local/MATLAB/R2013a/bin/matlab -desktop
```

Answer (score 4):

### For Ubuntu 16.04 and MATLAB R2016b

Find your preferable picture in .png format and rename it `matlab.png`.

1. Execute:

   ```
   sudo cp matlab.png /usr/share/pixmaps/
   ```

   The above command copies your icon to the appropriate folder.
2. Execute:

   ```
   sudo gedit /usr/local/share/applications/matlab.desktop
   ```

   Then copy the following lines on `matlab.desktop`:

   ```
   [Desktop Entry]
   X-AppInstall-Package=matlab-support
   X-AppInstall-Popcon=10
   X-AppInstall-Section=multiverse
   Version=1.0
   Type=Application
   Terminal=false
   Exec=/usr/local/MATLAB/R2016b/bin/matlab -desktop
   Name=MATLAB
   Icon=/usr/share/pixmaps/matlab.png
   Categories=Development;Math;Science
   Comment=Scientific computing environment
   StartupNotify=true
   StartupWMClass=com-mathworks-util-PostVMInit
   X-Ubuntu-Gettext-Domain=app-install-data
   ```
3. Go on Dash and type `matlab`.
4. Pick the icon from Dash and move in onto Launcher.

#### Τέλος! The end!

Answer (score 2):

To my experience by far, the far simplest solution I have figured out yet is to simply install "matlab-support" through apt-get. It solves not only this issue but others as well. Just pop open a terminal and type

```
   sudo apt-get install matlab-support -y
```

It will ask for the location of Matlab. Mine is at `/usr/local/MATLAB/R2017b`.

Comment: works for me! Faster than making a .dekstop file

Answer (score 0):

Create a symbolic link in `/usr/local/bin`, i.e. as su

```
ln -s /usr/local/MATLAB/R2013a/bin/matlab /usr/local/bin/matlab
```

Once MATLAB is running, an icon should appear in the launcher toolbar. Right click it and lock it to the launcher.

Comment: That works so I can run it by typing `matlab` in the terminal. However, the lock to launcher is not working. Is there a way to make it show up when I search matlab in the unity launcher or so that I can have a desktop icon for it?

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu 18.04
For me this works perfectly ...

Open a terminal and then

1. Download your own icon:

   ```
   sudo wget http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/21/Matlab_Logo.png -O /usr/share/icons/matlab.png
   ```
2. Create .desktop file:

   ```
   sudo touch /usr/share/applications/matlab.desktop
   ```
3. Edit your .desktop file

   ```
   sudo gedit /usr/share/applications/matlab.desktop
   ```
4. Paste the following into the .desktop file:

   ```
   #!/usr/bin/env xdg-open
   [Desktop Entry]
   Type=Application
   Icon=/usr/share/icons/matlab.png
   Name=MATLAB R2018a
   Comment=Start MATLAB - The Language of Technical Computing
   Exec=matlab -desktop
   Categories=Development;
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Just create a file with notepad: **[matlab.desktop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2P4Mm.png)**
And copy the code below:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Name=MATLAB
Exec=/home/**USER**/MATLAB/R2023b/bin/matlab -desktop
Icon=/home/**USER**/MATLAB/R2023b/resources/coreui/matlab/splash.png
Terminal=false
```

Then save the file in the folder: Desktop

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem, and fund that much of the difficulty came from Matlab installing the .desktop file into `~/.local/share/applications/`, rather than `/usr/share/applications/`. With that in mind, my solution:

1. Ensure that you can launch matlab by typing `matlab` in terminal. If not, then you can install a sym link to do so, or replace my `matlab` commands below with the full path to the matlab executable.
2. Download a [matlab icon](http://people.brandeis.edu/~dlaz/utils/icons/matlab.png) and save it to `~/.local/share/icons/matlab.png`
3. Create a new file: `~/.local/share/applications/matlab_version.desktop` with the contents:
       [Desktop Entry]
       Encoding=UTF-8
       Version=1.0
       Type=Application
       Name=MATLAB
       Icon=matlab.png
       Exec=matlab -desktop
       StartupNotify=fals[
       Terminal=false
4. Check that the file you just created (matlab_version.desktop) has permissions set to be executable.
5. Navigate to ~/.local/share/applications/ using nautilus file explorer, and then double click on matlab_version (it hides the file extension here)
6. That should launch matlab. If it works, then right-click on the matlab icon in the unit launcher and then select 'lock to launcher'. If it doesn't work, then check that the file has execute permissions, and that your sym link is working.