# Problem running Matlab from launcher icon

Tags: unity, software-installation, launcher, .desktop, matlab

I referred this link for my problem:
[How to create launcher icon](https://askubuntu.com/questions/401948/how-to-create-launcher-icon)

Though my **matlab icon is already created**, whenever I click it this shows up for a few seconds:

[image: Matlab splash screen appearing temporarily]

Then, the **application closes itself** automatically!

I have to **run it from the terminal** every time for MATLAB to actually open and go beyond the splash screen:

```
/usr/local/MATLAB/R2017a/bin/matlab
```

Though the above method works perfectly, I want to be able to run it properly from the icon, I can't seem to figure out what the problem is.

As mentioned in the link above, of the top voted answer I did this first:

```
sudo ln /usr/share/app-install/desktop/matlab-support:matlab.desktop /usr/share/applications/matlab.desktop
```

Then deleted all the contents of the .matlab file and replaced it with:

```
[Desktop Entry]
X-AppInstall-Package=matlab-support
X-AppInstall-Popcon=4
X-AppInstall-Section=multiverse

Version=1.0
Type=Application
Terminal=false
Exec=/usr/local/MATLAB/R2017a/bin/matlab -desktop
Name=MATLAB
Icon=/usr/share/app-install/icons/_usr_share_icons_hicolor_48x48_apps_matlab.png
Categories=Development;Math;Science
Comment=Scientific computing environment
StartupNotify=true
StartupWMClass=com-mathworks-util-PostVMInit

X-Ubuntu-Gettext-Domain=app-install-data
```

When I retry doing the first step, I get the following message:

```
ln: failed to create hard link '/usr/share/applications/matlab.desktop': File exists
```

Then I tried creating a soft-link as suggested in one of the answers:

`ln -s /usr/local/MATLAB/R2017a/bin/matlab /usr/local/bin/matlab`

Nothing seems to work for me, help!

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 problems with your approach.

1. you use hardlink instead of symlink explained [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/108771/what-is-the-difference-between-a-hard-link-and-a-symbolic-link#43599)
2. you switched target and link paths. It should be `sudo ln -s pathToLink pathToTarget`

So this is the corrected command:

`sudo ln -s /usr/share/applications/matlab.desktop /usr/share/app-install/desktop/matlab-support:matlab.desktop`

Comment: I copied and ran the exact corrected command that you suggested, but it gave me a similar message: `ln: failed to create symbolic link '/usr/share/app-install/desktop/matlab-support:matlab.desktop': File exists`